# Android - Facebook Event track Purchase

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-events

I'm working on implementing the Facebook tracking of `Purchase` event in Android. I followed the guide here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android, and made a custom `Bundle` to send to FB.

The problem is, on the Facebook page of events, I don't see the `Value` column updated for the `Purchase` event.

This is the code:

```
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CURRENCY, mCurrency);
        parameters.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT_TYPE, mProductType);
        parameters.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT_ID, mPurchaseID);
        Double valueToSum = 12.042289; //this is how the price looks like

        AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this);
        logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_PURCHASED, valueToSum, parameters);
```

My problem is that, the `valueToSum` **does not sum in the Facebook Events page**. It's always shown as "-".

Any ideas what I am actually doing wrong?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a while for the data to update on the dashboard. Try checking it the next day or so ...

Comment: Yes, indeed. This was the issue. It took roughly 30 hours for Data to appear in the Analytics dashboard. Thanks.